# Possible cause of inconsistent data

Tags: cassandra

The environment: C* 3.x with multiple regions where each region has 10~ nodes.

We are observing several cases of inconsistent data. Around 1K rows (out of 500+K) cannot be found in one datacenter (while can be found in another datacenter) unless the consistency all is set.

I understand `Frequent data deletions and downed nodes are common causes of data inconsistency` according to the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesManualRepair.html)

We randomly check some items and we never execute deletion on them. And we believe this is true for most of rows. So we would like to know what other possible causes of inconsistent data could be and how can we prevent it beside the regular repair.

Comment: Your question is too vague, as there are many variables to consider: how many replicas are in place? topography? what consistency level has been used for writes and for reads? repairs? volume of data? what is the table model? are there TTLs in place?

Comment: Not programming related, so probably belongs on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

So if you're sure that you're not doing deletes, the other main causes of data inconsistencies are:

- Using TTLs with `gc_grace_seconds` set too low or to zero.
- In-place updates with system clocks on each node not in-sync.
- Write backpressure.
- Dropped hints.

With TTLs, you want to make sure you're giving the tombstones a chance to replicate.  That's the reason `gc_grace_seconds` defaults to 864000 seconds (ten days).  If that value is too low, then the tombstones are marked for removal too quickly.  Thus, the data *behind* the tombstone reappears.

With in-place updates and out-of-sync clocks, the idea is that newly written data is valid and replicated but the `WRITETIME` is too far behind one or more nodes' system clocks.  This means that the newly written data will not take effect until the system time is >= to the data's `WRITETIME`.

You could also be in a scenario where the DC in-question is getting hammered with writes so much that the write backpressure builds up to the point where writes are being dropped.  If you see one or more nodes with CPU or disk I/O spiking, then this might be happening.

The last point, where if you have nodes which are frequently appearing to be down, then their neighboring nodes will build-up hints.  This could happen with a bad network connectection/routing that makes some nodes "appear" to be down to others.  In any case, those hints automatically stop collecting after 3 hours.  This setting is configurable with the `max_hint_window` in the cassandra.yaml.

Either way, inconsistent data doesn't really just happen on its own.  It's usually the symptom of another problem.

**TL DR;**
Check:

- `gc_grace_seconds` on tables using TTL.
- Check the system clock on all nodes.
- Check your nodes for high CPU and/or high disk I/O.
- Check for nodes where hints typically build up, and verify in the logs that they are getting sent.